# Is My Interpretation Valid for Heward's Handy Spice Pouch?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

To my understanding, the amount of spice you can take out of Heward's Handy Spice Pouch is theoretically infinite per charge, since I assume they are redefining the word "pinch" in the description to "enough (amount) to season a single meal". Wouldn't that mean I could create enough seasoning to season a world's worth of food? **Is my interpretation correct?** Obviously it's not balanced, and classical RAI would say I'm only partly correct, but I would personally like to have a finer idea of what's solidly within and without both RAI and RAW bounds, so a simple question like this would help. Anyway, here's the definition, emphasis mine:

> This belt pouch appears empty and has 10 charges. While holding the pouch, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges, speak the name of any nonmagical food seasoning (such as salt, pepper, saffron, or cilantro), and remove a **pinch** of the desired seasoning from the pouch. **A pinch is enough to season a single meal**. The pouch regains 1d6 + 4 expended charges daily at dawn.

Depending on the answer I get from this question, I might ask a reasonable homebrew to mitigate the abuse of this, but I'll postpone that for later.

Comment: To explain my downvote, this seems like a really long justification for a very odd interpretation when you actually highlighted the important and obvious answer yourself. It feels like an "I want this to do x, and will lawyer these words until you prove me wrong" question.

Comment: I think this can reduced to "The definition is ... My interpretation is since it doesn't define how big a meal is (it can be eaten by one or two or even a meal for the world), then I can take a LOT of seasoning. Is my interpretation correct?"

Comment: what do you think "a pinch" means?

Comment: Google "Infinite Oregano"

Comment: In order to help you improve your question, if it can be, you are advised to view some old commercials for Skoal dip tobacco, with Walt Garrison, to see visually how much a pinch is.  "Just a pinch between cheek and gum" is the amount he demonstrates. [This poster may help](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/657384876827268408/)

Comment: Tobacco, the solution to all life's questions

Comment: @Vylix Edited for conciseness.

Comment: @AnnaAG That's what was my primary confusion about this question, which Nobody the Hobgoblin clarified. I had assumed that "pinch" was being redefined according to the description as "enough (amount) to season a single meal (unknown amount of people)".

Comment: @MattVincent I Googled it and that was exactly my mindset, haha. Thanks for the amusing trundle through a cooking website.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yeah, I'm realizing that I was just delusional and caught on an unimportant piece of information that was completely changed the moment I had the correct info. Thanks for the efforts though. I wish it was the amount in the poster, since that's definitely more than 1/8th of a tsp, which kinda cripples my dreams of hoarding expensive spices and getting rich quick from a tiny pouch branded by some guy named Heward.

Comment: I could have probably found a better example, but that's the first one that I figured would have a good enough picture ...

Comment: @JThompson Due to curiosity: 1 lb saffron = 13.333 cups = 640 tsp's = 5120 pinchs; 1 lb saffron = 15 gp = 1500 cp; 5120 pinchs / 1500 cp = 3.4 pinchs per cp. So you could generally make up to 1-2 cp per day in saffron with this item. Indeed not for getting rich.

Comment: @Journer That's pretty helpful, actually; it's not much for getting rich, no, but I could make pocket change off it. I think it'll better serve its original function of being used in conjunction with cooking, which can be sold for more than what the pinch of saffron is worth. Thanks for the post and info!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You're good mate; I appreciate the effort. Nobody the Hobgoblin presented a more easily referable case, i.e. one that refers to a widely accepted source like the dictionary. With tobacco, a pinch can have some variation, link if I said a pinch of wood, but I pinched a branch. It's interesting to note that pinches have been used in pop media, and I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### No, the interpretation is not valid. You get normal pinches and can't produce unlimited wealth from a common item

The pouch says (emphasis added):

> This belt pouch appears empty and has 10 charges. While holding the pouch, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges, speak the name of any nonmagical food seasoning (such as salt, pepper, saffron, or cilantro), and **remove a pinch of the desired seasoning** from the pouch. **A pinch is enough** to season a single meal. The pouch regains 1d6 + 4 expended charges daily at dawn.

English words have their common meaning, so a pinch is (Oxford languages):

> an amount of an ingredient that can be held between fingers and thumb.

That is the amount. It is able to season a single meal. When the haversack speaks about seasoning a single meal, that is a single meal, for a single person.

You might argue that a meal for a giant might not reasonably be seasoned by a single pinch, as it is too large, but that still works: this is a magic item and the item says the pinch is sufficient to season the meal. Its magic. And even if you went with your interpretation of a meal for the world (which I think is quite obviously not the intended one), this one small pinch would be all that is needed. You don't get more spice.

#### Commmon magic items

Consider also this introduction to common magic items in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 136):

> The Dungeon Master's Guide includes many magic items of every rarity. The one exception are common items; that book includes few of them. This section introduces more of them to the game. **These items seldom increase a character's power, but they are likely to amuse players and provide fun roleplaying opportunities.**

Being able to create unlimited amounts of highly valuable spices would be economy breaking and quite powerful. Saffron is a trade good and one pound of it is worth 15 gp, freely useable to trade. Being able to create unlimted amounts of it is equivalent to being able to create arbitrary amounts of gold. This cannot be the purpose of this common magic item. It‘s to have some fun roleplaying that you can cook delicious meals for your party (or some important NPC) because you have this cool, magic spice bag.

Comment: :) pinch is a pinch is a pinch

Comment: The economy of any D&D game is a mushy thing. Also, cooking for important NPCs might be an even better use of this magic bag.

Comment: Valid. I see where my misunderstanding was, which was believing that they provided their own definition for what a "pinch" was, as opposed to relying on dictionaries, but now I see they were saying the pinch, 1/8 tsp, is magically able to flavor an entire meal. A bit aggressive in the wording, but thank you for the reply and thoroughness of your answer. Checked.

Answer (score 4):

### Single meal refers to a meal for a single eater

Since your other (now deleted) question on this has been closed as a duplicate of this, let me address it more explictly and specifically in an answer to this question.

The argument that you could flavor a meal for an entire army relies on the defintion of the term meal, which by the dictionary is limited to a single *sitting*, not a single *person*, and can include several people sitting together and sharing that meal.

And you are right that in this regard the feature has been written somewhat sloppily, and if one just relied on that one word, this could work. But you have to look at the entire text and nature of the item to understand what it does.

And from the context, it is clear that "single meal" here really must be an abbreviation of "meal for a single eater":

1. This is a **common magic item**, and "*These items seldom increase a character's power, but they are likely to amuse players and provide fun roleplaying opportunities.*". Being able to flavor a meal for an entire army or village is not as powerful as producing unlimited amounts of spices worth fortunes, but is still powerful. It would be worth a lot for emprires and armies who can sustain their armies with great food for a pittance (as the value of a common magic item is at most 100 gp), and so that does not fit.
2. It says "**single** meal", and if the feature just wanted you to be able to flavor a meal, it could just say meal. So what is the single for? A meal is already a meal. If we accept the item cannot flavor artifically large meals based on value and power, then the natural answer is that single here refers to a single eater.
3. Lastly, think about it in the context of a **typcial adventuring party**, which consists of 3-5 characters, with maybe an NPC henchman or two. The *pouch* regains 1d6+4 expended uses, so every day regains on average 7-8 uses. If you treat a "single meal" to mean a "meal for a single person", then this means it is able to supply enough meals for the main cooking rest of that party every day. It fits, while cooking 7-8 dinners per day does not. This is an item that is supposed to provide some fun roleplaying, and that is a good match for the owner of the *pouch* being the chef for the group.

(As an aside, in common use of language a meal also can refer to a meal for a single person. I used to live India for a while, and there you could buy a "meal" in restaurants, which was a typcial combo of rice and various spices and chutneys, for one person. They probably would have had a good laugh if you came in with a dictionary and tried to make them give you enough food for the whole group, based on the fact that a meal is defined not by person but by sitting).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't expect a response to the closed question, so I appreciate you going out of your way to explain that for me. I didn't think of it that way, so this helps me to understand not only the description of the item, but also a more general method of understanding things in context and using inductive reasoning, as opposed to my usual method of using deductive reasoning. +1